# Exclude taxonomy term parent in view

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

i have a menu with this structure:

Item name: Sport
Item link: taxonomy/term/35

And taxonomy terms with this structure:

Football tid 35
- Smallfotball tid 38 parentid 35
- Bigfootball tid 55 parent id 35

When i access to menu link my view displays all content that has taxonomy term id 35 and his childs. ( i use this contextual filters Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth) and Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier)

I need only displays Childs and exclude contents with taxonomy term 35 (taxonomy parent, id menu link), i resolve this with filter criteria where (term) Taxonomy term: Parent term (!= 0) but in other cases does not works, for example in this (when parent is a children of other term):

Football tid 35
- Smallfotball tid 38 parentid 35
- Bigfootball tid 55 parent id 35
  - Big2football tid 56 parent id 55
  - Big343football tid 66 parent id 55

if menu link is

Item name: Bigfootball
Item link: taxonomy/term/55

display:

- Bigfootball tid 55 parent id 35

  - Big2football tid 56 parent id 55
  - Big343football tid 66 parent id 55

and i need displays only

- Big2football tid 56 parent id 55
- Big343football tid 66 parent id 55